# Android the starting value of Edittext must not be the first Item on my array(Edittext Spinner)

Tags: java, android, spinner

This must be a simple problem that i might again overlooked. Here is my problem
I have a string array on my string.xml

```
<string-array name="country_array">
    <item>Alabama</item>
    <item>Florida</item>
    <item>Los Angeles</item>
    <item>Virginia</item>
    <item>California</item>
    <item>Texas</item>
    <item>Hawaii</item>
    <item>Miami</item>
    <item>New Jersey</item>
    <item>Boston</item>
    <item>Philadelphia</item>
    <item>VaChina</item>
 </string-array>
```

So now I am calling in on my main activity and placed it on my spinner

```
selectedCountry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCity);
    //get the spinner from resource
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCountry);

    //then defining ArrayAdapter using country_array
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter =ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.country_array,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    //set the appearance of widget items that show when open the widget
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    //set the adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    //set the action listener
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);
```

Now on my onclicklistener of my spinner this is my code

```
View.OnClickListener selectCountry = new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCountry);
             spinner.performClick();
         }  
    };

    private OnItemSelectedListener listener =new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        //do what ever you want to do when item selected
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
                long id) {
            //i get the item using selected item position and set it into selectedCountry
            selectedCountry.setText(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());          
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }

    };
```

Every thing works fine until I figured out that on my selectedCountry text is the first item on my array.
Is there anyway that I could add a default value on my edittext?

Comment: You want default value for Spinner Or EditText??

Comment: why don't you set an default value to EditText when you are creating your EditText, or do an `Events.postEvent()` to select one from Spinner.

Comment: Ive already tried that sir adding this one selectedCountry.settext("Trial"); on my oncreate but the data still return to the first item on the array

Comment: Do you want to show "Select Country" in spinner??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add "Select Country" in your String array as first item.

Like

```
<string-array name="country_array">
    <item>Select Country</item>
    <item>Alabama</item>
    <item>Florida</item>
    <item>Los Angeles</item>
    <item>Virginia</item>
    <item>California</item>
    <item>Texas</item>
    <item>Hawaii</item>
    <item>Miami</item>
    <item>New Jersey</item>
    <item>Boston</item>
    <item>Philadelphia</item>
    <item>VaChina</item>
 </string-array>
```

then

add below code in onItemSelected()

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,int position, long arg3) 
{
    if(!spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Select Country"))
    {
          selectedCountry.setText(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());  
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir the problem is when I clicked on the spinner, it also shows the "Select Country". Is there any way to hide that text? Actually this is just my trial session because I will use data from database.. Please pardon me as I am just switching from asp.net

Comment: I don't have another answer for you, unfortunately. :P

Comment: Well, that would do I guess I have to recreate again but thanks you gave me an idea..